# How to call retrivedata by id procedure from sql server

Tags: asp.net

I created stored procedure for retrieve data by Id in sql server

```
Create procedure [dbo].Retrievebyid(@ID int)
as begin  
       select [Name],  
       [Manufacturer],  
       [Model]  
       from DbTable where ID=@ID
end
```

Now goto visual studio create project and take web-aplication in that added 
 ADO.NET EntityModel.
    And i try to call that SP but i don't know how do it.

```
Entities db = new Entities();  
void Edit()  
{  
       str = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["id"]);  
       db.Retrievebyid(ID: str);  
       Retrievebyid_Result dbb = new Retrievebyid_Result();  
       TextBox1.Text = dbb.Name;  
       TextBox2.Text = dbb.Manufacturer;  
       TextBox3.Text = dbb.Model;  
}
```

But its not get the data could u please solve my problem

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? You can do something like `Database.SqlQuery<ResultClassName>("EXEC Retrievebyid @ID", IDParameter)` where `IDParameter` is `SqlParameter` type.

Comment: Could u plz rewrite the below code                                                         
                Entities db = new Entities();  
                void Edit()  
{  
       str = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["id"]);  
       db.Retrievebyid(ID: str);  
       Retrievebyid_Result dbb = new Retrievebyid_Result();  
       TextBox1.Text = dbb.Name;  
       TextBox2.Text = dbb.Manufacturer;  
       TextBox3.Text = dbb.Model;  
}